# Why didn't Dumbledore keep Harry with himself after the Potters got killed?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

Why couldn't have Dumbledore keep Harry with himself? I know about the charm that was on harry due to Lily's sacrifice. But if Harry had lived with Dumbledore :

1. Dumbledore was an extraordinary talented wizard as compared to other Magical families who could adopt Harry. He could provide excellent protection to Harry.
2. Imagine what the boy could have become. He could have been trained for what was waiting out there. **Dumbledore knew that Voldemort was still alive** and he also knew  **the prophecy that it was Harry only who can kill Voldemort**. So he could have trained harry from the beginning.

The answer on the basis of which this was marked duplicate only talks about protection. But Dumbledore could easily provide that along with some other benefits as the one I mentioned above. And of Harry getting arrogant, I am sure Dumbledore would have looked after that.

Comment: https://youtu.be/IpYHbdh9yTM?t=143

Comment: @CreationEdge No it can't be...

Comment: Yes, it can be. Duplicates can happen because of answers, not just questions. The answer in the dupe is your answer.

Comment: It is not....The answer says about the blood protection, I know, but Think of Dumbledore, can't he give Harry An Awesome amount of protection?

Comment: @CreationEdge look at my new edit..

Comment: This is what troubled me when I first watched Harry Potter movie...

Comment: How is it duplicate please clarify...its a same kind of question but please note the difference. Here I am asking about dumbledore, the greatest wizard to live. Could he not provide a brilliant protection to harry ?

Comment: Dumbledore is a headmaster of a school, and has shown no inclination or skill towards parenting. Adopting a baby and raising him, while shielding him from his life story, is no small task.

Comment: But if it is a question of defeating world's most evil wizard, shouldn't he consider it?.... oh and there was the flawed plan that kept him from keeping Harry after he joined the school. ..well ok then....but please, this question is not a duplicate of the above said question. .it is new in a context. .

Comment: The answer boils down to the same thing: Harry was safest living with the Dursleys. Dumbledore could have possibly protected him, but by sending Harry to live with the Dursleys he gave him the absolute best protection he could.

Comment: I think dumbledore said something of putting some charm on Harry too...

Answer (score 1):

Harry had to go back to his aunt's home because there was a charm over it which was placed using the protective power of Lily's love. He had to go there until he became of age (17 years old).

Comment: Hello and welcome to SCIFI.SE. Consider taking [the tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour). While this is a good answer, it could benefit from some editing to improve the format of it. Maybe add some quotes if you have the book with you ?

Comment: Please re read the question. ..